# What are the milestones where a user gets bonus reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus

When my reputation becomes 202, I get a +100 reputation bonus named as "trusted user". Are there any other bonuses like this, like when my total reputation reaches 1000 or above?

Comment: You do not get a reputation bonus when you become a trusted user. You're probably thinking about the account association bonus you receive (once) when joining another SE site.

Comment: The association bonus is one-off to get you past being unable to comment etc. You don't get another bonus further along; other rep is exclusively per-site.

Comment: ok....i understand

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Are there any other bonuses like this, when total reputation reaches on 1000 or above?

No.

---

The point of the association bonus is to give people whom we believe already know the basics of the system (given they managed to get to 200 reputation on one site) the basic reputation on all sites to let them use the basic functionality without requiring them to gain the reputation to manage those on each and every site (for instance - upvoting and commenting everywhere).

Comment: It's not a perfect system but it's better than not having it.